# Can I connect the "headphone out" of a ZOOM effects pedal (A3/G3) to a set of 2.1 stereo powered speakers and get decent sound?

Tags: guitar, speakers, effects-pedal

Is there anything I should be wary of? I'm planning to buy a guitar and kinda in doubt whether I should go for dedicated amp (like a blackstar id:core series) or get an effects pedal like a zoom g3/a3 and connect it to my speakers. Any advice please?

Comment: Not sure the pedal can power speakers on its own. Usually these can be plugged into an amp, then speaker. Headphone sockets will power headphones rather than full blown speakers.

Comment: Is it a *powered* 2.1 system, like you'd use with e.g. a computer?

Comment: Its this : http://www.sony.co.in/product/srs-d9 , a standard 2.1 stereo stuff that you'd plug in to your desktop/laptop.

Comment: Then yes, it will work fine.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have my doubts that it will be "fine" as in playable, listenable, audible above a backing tracks and pleasurable. It will *kind of* work, in the same way that peeing in a bottle can kind of work if you just can't pull the truck over.

Answer (score 1):

If your stereo has an "aux" input, of the kind you'd plug a separate CD player into, then yes, you can connect the output of most multi-effects pedals to this.

It's likely, in fact, that the output is labeled "headphone/line out". But any headphone output can be used as a "poor man's line out".

Answer (score 1):

Be wary of the headphone output levels in the pedal and the actual volume on the system in order to:

1) get a clean sound.

2) reduce the risk of blowing a speaker when using a heavy distortion or high gain effect.

It is common sense even when connecting to an amp but extra care is needed when using systems the way they are not intended to.

The Zoom G3 has a L/Mono/Phone output, so it can give you a nice line out signal, additionally you can connect the pedal in stereo using the L and R outputs and the correct plug adapters (from 1/4"phone plugs to RCA plugs) or with the stereo Phone output using a cable with an stereo 1/4" plug (or miniplug with an adapter) and the 2 RCA plugs to connect to the stereo.   system

http://www.zoom.co.jp/products/g3/spec/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it *can* be done but I don't think it's worth it.

Two possible outcomes:

A. You'll spend your whole life either wondering whether it's you that can't play or if it's your plastic box that sounds bad and hollow and gritty. you'll probably not be able to understand what's wrong with your playing and you **won't improve much, especially in terms of control, phrasing and dynamics**.

B. **You'll get bored** of the little box's hollow sound pretty fast and conclude that playing guitar ain't much fun after all. You'll try to resell the whole thing but will discover quick that there's no market for that.

[image: pic of sad guitarist]

My advice is: a **musical instrument** is a musical *instrument*, not a *device*.

You money is best spent on - well, **lessons**, you have a teacher, right? - and on a modeling amp like the [Vox Valvetronix](http://www.voxamps.com/valvetronix) series, you can get the [AD15VT](http://www.voxshowroom.com/uk/amp/ad15.html) model used for **well under $100** and it sounds great for all styles, from blues to metal.

[image: pic of valvetronix control panel]

It is especially good for a credible AC-30 emulation (if you are into jangly rock like R.E.M. or are after Brian May's sound) and for hard blues a la Stevie Ray Vaughan.

I know because I have one and it has made me **fall in love with guitar again**, after an **emulator connected to my monitors** sucked *all* love of guitar out of me.

Its high gain emulations aren't the best, but nothing, say, [a DS-2](http://cdn.roland.com/assets/images/products/gallery/ds2_gal.jpg) can't cure if you are so inclined.

Then again, **get a teacher first** and maybe see if he/she can help you choosing a good starter amp.

Just in case I haven't made myself clear:

1. **get a teacher**
2. **get a teacher**
3. **get a teacher**

**Defer all equipment-buying decisions** to *after* you've gotten yourself a good teacher - especially because a teacher **will help you choose** a guitar and amp that doesn't suck and help you get it set up, and believe me that there's plenty of unplayable, crappy pieces of wood out there.

Comment: Oh, also those Sony speakers are of little audiophile value anyway, as is pretty much any 2.1 rig with plastic 2" drivers that defer frequencies well above 80Hz to the "sub" (which isn't a sub anymore). Avoid like the plague except for use in the (home) office.

Comment: couldn't find any of that. So i bought a Blackstar id:Core 40. Sounds good! how do u think that compares with the vox ?

Comment: And, yeah, my amp has an emulated out, and even with a decent pair of headphones (m50) it sounds quiet and hollow.